# Correlation of lognormal processes

Tags: correlation, lognormal-distribution

Proposition: If X(t) is a lognormal process then corr(X(t),1/X(t))=-1.

1. What is a lognormal process? What are the differences between a lognormal process and a lognormal distribution?
2. Can anybody prove the above proposition?

Comment: AFAIK, a lognormal process is one whose logarithms form a [Gaussian process](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_process). However, the proposition is false: the points $(X(t), 1/X(t))$ necessarily lie on the hyperbola $y=1/x$, no part of which is linear, implying their correlation cannot be either $-1$ or $1$.  (The same reasoning shows, however, that the correlation between $\log(X(t))$ and $\log(1/X(t))$ is equal to $-1$.) In fact, the proposition is false for *any* process with a positive chance of attaining $3$ or more distinct values.

Comment: I totally agree with you. The propositions was asked in past FRM exams with possible answers -1,1,1/2,-1/2 and the "correct" result is -1.

Answer (score 1):

Answer taken from comments by whuber:  The proposed proposition is false. The points $(X(t), 1/X(t))$ necessarily lie on the hyperbola $y=1/x$, no part of which is linear, implying their correlation cannot be either $−1$ or 1. (The same reasoning shows, however, that the correlation between $\log(X(t))$ and $\log(1/X(t))$ is equal to $−1$.) In fact, the proposition is false for any process with a positive chance of attaining 3 or more distinct values.